# ModIfied Traveling Salesman

Tags: graph-algorithm, traveling-salesman

Given a graph structure that has asymmetric costs on the edges, is there a way to traverse a certain set of nodes at lowest cost if you can visit each node only once? Problem is formulated such that such a path must exist.

Answer (score 0):

Brute-force will eventually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star).

Comment: I attempted a USC algorithm, but it turned out to be almost equivalent to BFS (edge costs are large). I don't have a good guess for an admissible heuristic. Are there any sub-optimal solutions that find a 'pretty good' solution?

Comment: The zero heuristic is admissible :)  USC = ?

Comment: USC = uniform cost search. A* degenerates into USC with zero heuristic.

Comment: Why don't you use USC? You want something more effective?

Comment: Yes, USC is slower than a greedy brute force algorithm. I was just wondering of there was something more effective.